# What does Int use three bits for?

Tags: haskell, int

Unlike many langauges where `Int` is in the range *2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1* using one bit for the sign bit, Haskell instead uses the range *2<sup>29</sup> to 2<sup>29</sup>-1*, or in other words 29 bits + 3 bits for something else... I'm guessing one of those three are the sign bit, but what then are the remaining two bits used for?

Comment: .... 30 + 2 ......